# How can I display indent lines in front of markup?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, development-environment

In Visual Studio Code, you can see some lines in front of tags. How can I configure Visual Studio Code to show these lines?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is vertical rules,  To configure it, go to menu **`File → Preferences → Settings`** and add this to to your user or workspace settings:

```
"editor.rulers": [80,120]
```

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces

Answer (score 0):

They are known as "indent render guides", if you go to file > preferences > settings you can search for them there and toggle the setting on.